# Android Web View session not persisting after first page

Tags: php, android, cookies

I am making an app that makes a request to a web view with a particular URL base, and body depending on the user's search parameters. The web view loads the first view correctly, but when a selection inside the web view is made, we notice that the cookies with the search info have been lost.

I am new to Android development, but in iOS the whole process works like a charm. Any ideas on what might be different?

Here is my code, with a solution I tried using Cookie Sync Manager:

```
// WebView set up
        WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
        settings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance(); if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) { cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView,true); } else { cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true); }
        CookieSyncManager.getInstance().startSync();

        webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new AppBrowser(this));

        String url = "https://m.url.com/flights/search";
        if (source != null)
            webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(url, source, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
        else
            finish();
```

And here is my custom implementation of the web view:

```
public class AppBrowser
        extends WebViewClient {


    /**
     * Attributes
     */
    private ExecutorListener listener;


    public AppBrowser(ExecutorListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
        super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
        Toast.makeText(new WebViewActivity(), "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        FutureTaskManager.executeAfter(listener, "hide", 3, false);

        CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();

    }
}
```

Any ideas of what might be wrong with the persistence of the session?

Answer (score 0):

### **Check if the post domain matches the original domain**

I had a similar issue that took me forever to debug.

One tip I would give to anyone with the same issue is to check where the form is being posted to.

For instance if you are loading **m.domain.com** and the form is posting to **domain.com** or **www.domain.com** your app will be searching for the session data in **m.domain.com** but the session info will live in **www.domain.com** or **domain.com**.

Took me many hours and many cups of coffee to figure out this seemingly simple issue.